# How can I control the height of my left-right delimited equation part?

Tags: equations, amsmath

I have a simple equation, much like the following (I use the `braket` package) :

```
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{Y} = \Set{ x \in \mathcal{G} | \Vert x \Vert > d }
\end{equation}
```

My gripe with this equation's rendering is that the | and || are close to eachother and of the exact same height - I'd like the | bar to be bigger to make the symbols more distinct. One way to do this would be to make the whole `Set`, or left-right environment, a bit taller. How can I do this? Can I insert an invisible character that will make the whole thing bigger? Should I insert a higher | bar manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert a `\strut` before the `\Vert` (or anywhere so the extensible delimiters are affected):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{braket}% http://ctan.org/pkg/braket
\begin{document}
\noindent Original:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{Y} = \Set{ x \in \mathcal{G} | \Vert x \Vert > d }
\end{equation}
\verb|\strut|-ed:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{Y} = \Set{ x \in \mathcal{G} | \strut\Vert x \Vert > d }
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @levesque: `\strut` is a zero-width box that is inserted and depends on the font size. It has height 70% and depth 30% of `\baselineskip`. So, inserting `\strut` inserts a zero-width box of total height equivalent to `\baselineskip`, but perhaps deeper than the other content. Since the delimiters `{`...`|`...`}` are stretchable, they extend to compensate for this newly-introduced vertical strut.